# "Turn" initialized memory into shared memory with the SYSV API?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

To create a **new** and **empty** shared memory segment I can do something like:

```
int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, nbytes, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
int* new_array = (int*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

Now suppose `int* array` owns a chunk of pre-existing data. Something like

```
int* array = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
array[0] = 42;
array[1] = 24;
```

I'd like to turn this memory segment into a shared memory segment with the System V shared memory C API, on Linux.

> *How can I do this?*

I've tried stuff like

```
 int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, nbytes, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
 void* attach = shmat(shmid, array, SHM_RND);
```

and like

```
int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, nbytes, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
array = (int*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
```

but either shmat returns `(void*)-1` or `int* array` gets all its values set to zero.

Here's a full program that shows the failures:

```
/*
gcc shm0.c -o shm0 && ./shm0
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define NELEMENTS 3

void array_show(int* array, size_t nelements){
    puts("");
  for(int i=0; i < nelements; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", *(array + i));
}

int main(){
  const size_t nbytes = NELEMENTS * sizeof(int);
  int* array;
  posix_memalign((void**)&array, 16*16*16, nbytes);

  int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, nbytes, IPC_CREAT | 0777);

  // 1st try...
  void* attach = shmat(shmid, array, SHM_RND);
  if(attach == (void*)-1)
    puts("shmat() failed!");

  // 2nd try...
  memset(array, 1, nbytes);  // Fill array with dummy data!
  array_show(array, NELEMENTS);
  array = (int*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
  array_show(array, NELEMENTS);
  if(array[1] == 0)
    puts("array was reset!");

  // 3rd try
  array = (int*)shmat(shmid, array, 0);  // Now accessing, say, array[0] yields a segfault!

  shmdt(array);
}
```

---

Why SYSV shared memory and not `mmap()`? Because I'm using the [X11 MIT shared memory extension](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/shm.html), and, according to the docs:

> ... to be able to use this extension, your system must provide the SYSV shared memory primitives. There is not an mmap-based version of this extension. To use shared memory on Sun systems, you must have built your kernel with SYSV shared memory enabled ...

(If someone knows a way around this, or how to do this using `shm_open()`, I'd be delighted to hear about it.)

Comment: You cannot do what you want

Comment: Is it possible to do this with `mmap()` or `shm_open()`?

Comment: Consider *copying* some content into the shared memory segment

Comment: Yes, copying into the shared memory segment is what I'm already doing, but I'd like a zero-copy solution, since the data is already in memory, after all. There shouldn't be a need to copy it again!

Comment: Then create your shared memory segment *before* computing the data, and change your program to create that data inside the segment

Comment: @étale-cohomology, why not to allow the system to pick the address? 
e.g. `void *ptr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);` ?

Comment: As @BasileStarynkevitch said you should firstly map the shared segment associated with `shmid` and use this address later in your program.

Comment: @dshil Why not allow the system to pick the address? Because I want to turn an *existing* and *initialized* memory segment into a shared memory segment. The main assumption is that the memory segment has valuable and expensive-to-copy data and the question asks for a zero-copy solution to the problem (or something of similar speed). Initializing an empty shared memory segment an then copying everything to it is the naive, brute-force solution, and I'm looking for a more elegant solution =)

Comment: I get why what you want to do seems reasonable, but I think you're misunderstanding how `mmap()` and `shmat()` work.  The memory you got from `malloc()` and initialised came from libc.  Under the covers libc already asked the operating system for the address space to back your `malloc()` calls, either implicitly at process start-up or explicitly when you asked to `malloc()` more memory than can fit in the default address space.  `mmap()` and `shmat()` ask the operating system to reserve *more* address space, and can't ask the OS to allocate address space your process already has.

Comment: Shareability of address space can be provided by the OS when the address space is allocated to your process, but while other attributes of address space can be updated after the initial allocation, shareability isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, BasileStarynkevitch and WhilomChime. So Linux makes it impossible to change **shareability** of address space. Now I wonder what changes can be made to the kernel to allow this to happen...

Comment: Without *any* sense of what the security implications might be, from what I know about how these things are implemented (I once worked on implementing `mmap()` and `shm*()` APIs for the POSIX subsystem in Win2K) it wouldn't be impossible.  I can't speak to how adviseable it would be though!  I'm curious to know why building your data structures in an already shared segment isn't an option.

Comment: *"I'm curious why...."* Oh, building the data structure in an already shared segment *is* an option, and it's what I'm doing after reading your replies (thanks!), but I was curious to know *why* I had to do it in the first place, and whether it was a limitation of the SYSV API, a limitation of the OS, a limitation of the hardware, a limitation of the laws of physics, or a limitation of logic itself